# Google maps infobubble and markerwithlabel script 404 not found

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

These were working just recently and now I get 404 not found

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

Was this the official link or is there a new one?

UPDATE:

These links seem to work. Is this called hot linking? Is that a bad thing? Don't know how else to do it...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobubble/src/infobubble.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Infobox, Images and others assets are broken due to google-maps-utility-library-v3 [moving to github](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/255).

You can find it [here](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html).

Emergency solution: [infobox link](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js?r=466)

There's no problem using these links

Comment: Are my updated links a long term solution? Sorry, but I'm new to Google map API.

Comment: What is the real source?